# properties are shared between component instances

Tags: reactjs

In the React documentation, they say that I should store my `ref` elements as component properties:

```
render: function() {
  return <TextInput ref={(c) => this._input = c}>foobar</div>;
},
```

I'm doing so with a simple div element:

```
render: function() {
  return <div ref={c => (this.contextElement = c)} />;
},
```

The problem is that if I have multiple instances of the same component, `this.contextElement` get shared between all of them, and this breaks the logic of my component.

I know I could use `ref='contextElement'` but I don't want to use it because React say:

> Although string refs are not deprecated, they are considered legacy, and will likely be deprecated at some point in the future. Callback refs are preferred.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What are you wanting to share across the instances? state? props? functions?

Comment: I don't want to share nothing actually

Comment: `this` is always referencing that specific instance of the component, I'm not sure how you're seeing it being shared, unless you have multiple divs rendered inside the same component?